# Twisted post length limit

Tags: http, post, twisted

How do you set the limit on the length of a POST request in twisted? I've looked around in the docs and can't find anything. It would even help if I knew the default limit.

Comment: Why would there be a limit? I'm pretty sure there is no default limit. If you want to impose one for some reason, let us know what exactly you're using (e.g., `twisted.web.client.HTTPClientFactory`?) and what it should do when the data is past the limit.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't, I haven't tested. But I do want a limit to prevent someone from spamming a huge amount of data. I'm using `twisted.web.resource.Resource` wrapped in a `twisted.application.internet.TCPServer`.

Comment: Oh, for *incoming* post data. I misunderstood, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there is a default limit on the size of incoming POST data, but you could pretty easily impose one by overriding the `Request.handleContentChunk()` method, with something like:

```py
from twisted.web import server

class SizeLimitingRequest(server.Request):
    def handleContentChunk(self, data):
        if self.content.tell() + len(data) > self.size_limit_on_post_data:
            raise SomeKindOfError("too much data nooooooo")
        return server.Request.handleContentChunk(self, data)
```

the actual method you'd be overriding is in `twisted.web.http.Request`, which is a superclass of `server.Request`. To make use of your shiny new class, just set your `Site` instance's `requestFactory` attribute:

```py
mysite.requestFactory = SizeLimitingRequest
```